paste animatio to model
I downloaded a animation from Mixamo. A walking loop animation.
When i try to copy the animation from the armature to the Model on the right, it fails to work, i tried to change the names of the bones, i also have tried copy&paste a separate animation/keyframes from the right army into the model's right arm.


How did you try to copy the animation? You can't just copy and paste into another model. CG dive has done a series of videos on using Mixamo animations with Blender. Start at video 10 from this series.

My first mistake was trying to use an old Mixamo version: I had to go look up Mixamo for blender 4.2(Mixamo_blender4). On the official website there was only the blender3 version, an old version that did not work for blender4.
In the video you recommended i followed 6:40 and forward and it worked! thank you!

Yes. I think that Mixamo update is from a third-party source not from Adobe and seems to work fine.
